# Why would aircraft engines be mounted with "toe out"?

Tags: aircraft-design, engine, multi-engine

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_DC-4E), on the Douglas DC-4E...

> [...] the four 1,450 hp (1,080 kW) Pratt & Whitney R-2180-A Twin Hornet 14-cylinder radials were all **mounted with noticeable toe-out, particularly the outer pair**.

<sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>

Why would the engines be [mounted toe-out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toe_(automotive)), instead of straight in line with the direction of flight? Is this practice common today?

Comment: The first thought that comes to my mind is a better thrust line in an engine out situation. However, toe-out would be counter productive in such a scenario, I should think. Technical specs seem to show 2.5° and 3° toe-out for the inboard and outboard engines respectively.

Comment: I think we posted at the same time!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[According to this source](http://www.airvectors.net/avdc4.html)

> The engines were toed out slightly to improve engine-out handling;
>   three tailfins were used to ensure that the aircraft could keep flying
>   more or less straight if both engines on one wing went down.

I belive it was done to keep the thrust more equal in the event of an outboard engine loss, i.e. they are inline with the direction of flight when an engine loss occurs. Keep in mind that at the time these planes were designed engine failure was a [[very]common thing](http://www.flyingmag.com/what-happened-piston-twin) and the mentality was a bit different than it is now. If a little bit of toe out mounting took a speed toll but made the aircraft far more controlable in the event of an engine loss it was considered worth while.

In modern multi-engine propellor aircraft [counter rotating propellors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-rotating_propellers) (left side and right side props spin oposite directions) are generally employed to fix this problem and avoid the [critical engine issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_engine). I do belive that some single engine aircraft still do employ a slightly canted engine position for this reason.

Comment: But *why* does the toe-out improve such engine out handling?

Comment: Puts the thrust line closer to the center of mass

Comment: Which way would the engine be canted in a single engine plane to combat asymmetric thrust in an engine-out situation?

Comment: Is there any thrust in single engine engine-out situation?

Comment: @vasin1987: No, but now the turning tendencies normally present from torque, P-factor, etc. are gone.

Comment: @FreeMan: My first R/C model (a Carl Goldberg Eagle 2) called for a bit of right thrust to counter left-turning tendencies, and down thrust because of the high wing. I don't know if full-scale planes do that.

Comment: @vasin1987 - kinda my point! :) However, @ Fred Larson - interesting... I, obviously, hadn't thought about that.

Comment: Toe-out will provide a small thrust vector in the outboard direction which will help counter the turning tendency into the failed engine.  Depending on the aircraft it can also provide additional airflow over the tail to improve rudder effectiveness.

Comment: This is a good answer but could be improved.  Specifically, I think that this is not actually true:  "In modern multi-engine propellor aircraft counter rotating propellors (left side and right side props spin oposite directions) are generally employed". As far as I know. counter-rotating props are the exception to the general rule.  It would be interesting to include a few example of modern a/c w/ counter-rotating props but I think it would improve the answer to alter the sentence to indicate that they are unusual cases.